# Выравнивание текста в Toast

Tags: java, android, android-toast

Возможно ли как-нибудь выравнять текст внутри тоста по центру?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Задайте вьюхе тоста `Gravity.CENTER`

[Отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3522023/center-text-in-a-toast-in-android)

```
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Centered\nmessage", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
TextView v = (TextView) toast.getView().findViewById(android.R.id.message);
if( v != null) v.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
toast.show();
```

Comment: Надо же, я думал только напролом через свою разметку это делается :D

Answer (score 2):

Создайте разметку тоста

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/custom_toast_layout_id"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#000000"
android:gravity="center"
android:padding="5dp" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

</LinearLayout>
```

И показываете `Toast`

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_toast,
    (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.custom_toast_layout_id));
    TextView text = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.text);
    text.setText("Button is clicked!");
    Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
    toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    toast.setView(layout);
    toast.show();
```

P. S. Просто на будущее, мало ли, вдруг захотите чего-то еще

[Отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11288475/custom-toast-in-android-a-simple-example)